# Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>
    <c:forTokens items="Zara,nuha,roshy" delims="," var="name">
    <c:out value="${name}"/><p>
    </c:forTokens>
</body>
</html>
```

when I try to start it I there is an error

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:358)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    servlets.MyServlet.doProcess(MyServlet.java:51)
    servlets.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:26)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

my permission exhibited in another project in which all the works

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>JavaSiteEE</groupId>
> <artifactId>JavaSiteEE</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <packaging>war</packaging> <dependencies>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>     <version>3.1.0</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javaee</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
>     <version>5</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>     <version>5.1.17</version>
>     <type>jar</type>
>     <scope>compile</scope>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>jstl</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
>     <version>6.0</version>
>     <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
>     <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
>     <version>1.4</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
>     <version>2.1.13</version>
> </dependency> </dependencies> <build>
> <plugins>
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>         <source>1.7</source>
>         <target>1.7</target>
>     </configuration>
> </plugin>
>
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.1.1</version>
>     <configuration>
>         <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
>     </configuration>
> </plugin>
> </plugins> </build> </project>
> ```
>
> in another project the exact same settings and all is normally displayed

Answer (score 1):

I believe this  is explained in a different question by [Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon):

> The javax:javaee-api is only intended for compiling against, not for
>   running against, including unit tests. If you need classes suitable
>   for running against, you really need a full Java EE application
>   server.
>
> Also, note to everyone - THERE IS NO JEE!!!  The correct name is "Java
>   EE". Thanks.

Source: [ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948598/classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract)