# Test servlet API with Mockito

Tags: java, servlets, mockito

I have `AddBookController`:

```
public class BookAddController extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB(name = "BuyerServiceEJB")
    private BuyerServiceInterface buyerService;

    @EJB(name = "AuthorServiceEJB")
    private AuthorServiceInterface authorService;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Book newBook = new Book();
        newBook.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        newBook.setAuthor(authorService.findAuthorById(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("author_id"))));
        newBook.setBought(Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("sold")));
        newBook.setGenre(request.getParameter("genre"));
        newBook.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price")));
        buyerService.addNewBook(newBook);
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

And I have testing class:

```
public class BookAddControllerTest {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserServiceBean.class);
private Book testBook = new Book();
private Author testAuthor = new Author();

@Before
public void precondition(){
    logger.info("Add Book Controller Test");
    testBook.setName("Возера Радасці");
    testAuthor.setAuthor_id(1L);
    testBook.setAuthor(testAuthor);
    testBook.setBought(false);
    testBook.setGenre("postmodernism");
    testBook.setPrice(15);
}

@Test
public void testDoPost() {
    logger.info("Test post request processing");
    BookAddController bookAddController = Mockito.mock(BookAddController.class);
    HttpServletRequest testRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse testResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    BuyerServiceInterface buyerServiceInterface = Mockito.mock(BuyerServiceInterface.class);
    AuthorServiceInterface authorServiceInterface = Mockito.mock(AuthorServiceInterface.class);

    when(testRequest.getParameter("name")).thenReturn("Возера Радасці");
    when(testRequest.getParameter("author_id")).thenReturn("1");
    when(testRequest.getParameter("sold")).thenReturn("false");
    when(testRequest.getParameter("genre")).thenReturn("postmodernism");
    when(testRequest.getParameter("price")).thenReturn("15");

    bookAddController.doPost(testRequest, testResponse);

    verify(buyerServiceInterface, times(1)).addNewBook(testBook);
    verify(authorServiceInterface, times(1)).findAuthorById(Long.parseLong("1"));
    verify(bookAddController, times(1)).doGet(testRequest, testResponse);

}
```

I receive exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:18)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:98)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**Questions:**

1. Do I use correct approach of testing `doPost` method?
2. How to fix this exception?

Comment: I dont understand what you achieve by doing this `BookAddController bookAddController = Mockito.mock(BookAddController.class);` and then calling post to test on mock?

Comment: I use `mock` strategy for a first time. Could you, please, clarify how I should test `doPost` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user @SMA implies you're actually not testing anything since you're only operating on mocked code. What you'd want to do is to create an instance of your `BookAddController` and likely pass in mocked instances of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` when you call `doPost`. Otherwise you're not exercising any code that you've written, and thus you have no way of knowing if the actual code that you've written works or if any regressions occur.

As for the exception I suspect that it can be that `junit` does not have access to the java ee api. Include javaEE in your pom and it may work. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948598/classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract) for more info

Answer (score 2):

This is an exciting problem caused by Oracle not shipping method bodies for a number of classes - all you're getting is the API, which makes it impossible to actually use the JAR file for running anything. See this [JBoss Wiki article](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode) for more:

> This problem is likely the result of having the javax:javeee-api (or javax:javaee-web-api) library on your test classpath. If you have a Maven project, you likely have the following dependency in your POM file:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>javax</groupId>
>   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
>   <version>6.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> <dependency>  
>   <groupId>javax</groupId>  
>   <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>  
>   <version>6.0</version>  
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> This dependency provides you with the Java EE APIs, not the implementations. While this dependency works for compiling, it cannot be used for executing code (that includes tests).
>
> ### Background
>
> When these artifacts were published to the Maven repository, Sun/Oracle stripped out the code from classes that are classified as "implementations". So all the interfaces are code complete, yet any abstract class or implementation class has no code in it. Any attempt to use that class will likely blow up.
>
> Here's an excerpt from the argument as to why Sun/Oracle did this:
>
> > When one compiles, they want to run as well. By the way, we have been promoting full set of Java EE APIs which can only be used for compilation - they are stripped off method details. That way, user can't take those artifacts and try to use it in runtime.
>
> Basically, the javax:javaee-api and javax:javaee-web-api Maven artifacts aren’t the real deal -- they’re ‘stubs’. They’re great for easily providing the dependencies necessary for compilation, but they break entirely when you need to do something.
>
> The workaround: do not use the javax.javaee-api or javax:javaee-web-api artifacts! Instead, use the "real" artifacts that you need. Unfortunately, there is no Maven scope available that will exclude a dependency from the test classpath (though there is a classpathDependencyExcludes configuration option in the surefire plugin for blacklisting them during testing).

The solution to this is to use the following:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

or the the JBoss version, or some other version which contains actual implementations for the classes you are using.

Comment: `        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final-redhat-2</version>
        </dependency>` - helped me